# Negation rule for p tags that are not inside specific div element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This is my sample html.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<p>Text with red color</p>
</div>
<div id="temp">
<div style="margin:0px">
<p>
Text without red color
</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to apply "color:red" to all p elements that are not inside "div that has id=temp".

I used CSS negation like below but no luck:

```
p:not(div[id="temp"] p){
color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want this: https://jsfiddle.net/9n3jm4bg/1/

```
:not(#temp) > p { color:red; }
```

Comment: It will not select `p` elements that are out of `div` elements.

Comment: Correct, but in the provided code each p is inside a div. So I think this will work for the situation.

Comment: As Nasir said, your rule will not select p elements that are out of div elements. I want a rule that should select all p elements except the one which is inside "div that has id temp"

Comment: @ShrinathShetty I've updated my answer. This should work for any situation as long as the "div that has id temp" is the direct parent of the div. Although it would technically select anything that doesn't have a direct parent with id of temp (regardless if it is a div or not).

Comment: Yes now it is perfect but just for not directly nested `p` children.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Your rule i.e. :not(#temp) > p { color:red; } works only if p is a direct child of div with id "temp". What if p is not a direct child? Check my edited html?

Comment: If you can't guarantee some sort of html structure, I don't think it's possible to do this with :not. If you could guarantee that the structure was "#temp div p", you could use ":not(#temp) > div > p". But otherwise I think your best bet is using a combination of other CSS rules to get your desired text colors.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such selector because the CSS `:not()` pseudo selector works only with simple and one element selector like an ID, class, element or tag name and other similarities.

The documentation in MDN says:

> The negation CSS pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation **taking a simple selector X as an argument**. It matches an element that is not represented by the argument. **X must not contain another negation selector**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not

So the only way I am thinking of is to override the styles of the elements you want to not select with a higher priority CSS selector which only matches the elements you want to ignore.

Example link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyrKKW?editors=1000

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CSS Selector</title>
  <style>
    p {
      color: red;
    }

    #temp p {
      color: initial;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Praesent nonummy mi in odio.</p>
  <div id="temp">
    <p>Inside #temp div: fusce neque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Another p inside #temp div: raesent blandit laoreet nibh. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Inside other div: proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Donec mollis hendrerit risus.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that how you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0zL3wd/1/

```
div:not(#temp) p{
color:red;
}

<div id="temp">
  <p>text without red</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>text with red</p>
  <p>text with red</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Danish. Your rule doesn't work. Your rule will not select p elements that are out of div elements. I want a rule that should select all p elements except the one which is inside "div that has id temp"

Comment: In that case you can achieve this with normal css without :not, something like Nasir suggested.